# How accurate is this graph about learning curve and spaced repetition system?

Tags: learning, long-term-memory, working-memory, short-term-memory

This graph is taken from the article from Wired about Piotr Woźniak and his spaced repetition learning software SuperMemo: [Want to Remember Everything You'll Ever Learn? Surrender to This Algorithm](http://www.wired.com/2008/04/ff-wozniak/)

[image]

I would like to know how accurate this graph is:

- Is the axes and the lines accurate?
- When would the fifth reminder be?

Comment: Hi, the graphs seems about right. This paper also using memory decay to optimize learning: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/tops.12183/abstract;jsessionid=1EE00B01462ACBBBDA6E467198B56DE8.f03t03 . Facts are not 'just' remembered after 60 days btw. The forgetting curve just keeps becoming less steep. I also believe that this is simply a graph to give you an idea of what is happening, and used simplified values.

Comment: If you have since found an answer, don't hestitate to answer this question yourself. ;p

Comment: @StevenJeuris sadly, I haven't :(